# Ploting nested lists in dictionary - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scatter-plot

My dataset is looking something like this:

```
{'Berlin': [[1, 333]],
 'London': [[1, 111], [2, 555]],
 'Paris': [[1, 444], [2, 222], [3, 999]]}
```

And for each city now I need to make scatter plot, for example, the plot of Paris should have on x-axis numbers: 1 2 3, and on the y-axis: 444 222 999.

I have a really big dataset, so I would like to have 5 cities per plot.

My code is looking something like this, but on the output I get empty plots.

```
for town in dictionary_town:
    x=[]
    y=[]
    i+=1
    save_plot = 'path'+str(i)+'.png'

    for list in town:
        x.append(list[0])
        y.append(list[1])

    plt.style.use('dark_background')
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot( kind='scatter',x = x, y=y,label=town, s=30,figsize=(50, 20), fontsize=25, alpha=0.5)
    plt.ylabel("Population", fontsize=50)
    plt.title(str(i), fontsize=50)
    legend = plt.legend(fontsize=30, markerscale=0.5, ncol=1)
    plt.savefig(save_plot)
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimum working piece of code just to focus on saving graphs. I intentionally omitted graph-styling parts of your code to be simple.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictionary_town = {'Berlin': [[1, 333]],
                   'London': [[1, 111], [2, 555]],
                   'Paris': [[1, 444], [2, 222], [3, 999]]}

path = '/your_path_to_image_saving/' #pls change here
i = 0
for town, values in dictionary_town.items():
    x = []
    y = []
    i += 1
    save_plot = path + str(i) + '.png'
    for value in values:
        x.append(value[0])
        y.append(value[1])
    plt.figure()
    plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, label=town)
    plt.ylabel("Population")
    plt.title(str(i))
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.savefig(save_plot)
    plt.close()
```

I recommend you to start from here and add some stylings one by one to figure out what's wrong.

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**
Plot 5 cities at a time. If you want to change # of cities, change `chunk`. Also, if # of cities needs to be larger than 5, `colors` needs to be added accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dictionary_town = {'Berlin': [[1, 333]],
                   'London': [[1, 111], [2, 555]],
                   'Paris': [[1, 444], [2, 222], [3, 999]]}

colors = {1: 'r', 2: 'b', 3: 'g', 4: 'k', 5: 'grey'}

path = '/your_path_to_image_saving/' #pls change here
i = 0
chunk = 5
for town, values in dictionary_town.items():
    i += 1
    values = np.array(values)
    x = values[:,0]
    y = values[:,1]
    plt.scatter(x=x, y=y, label=town, color=colors[(i+1)%chunk+1])
    if i % chunk == 0:
        save_plot = path + str(i) + '.png'
        plt.ylabel("Population")
        plt.title(str(i))
        plt.legend(loc=4)
        plt.savefig(save_plot)
        plt.close()
    elif (i == len(dictionary_town)) & (i % chunk != 0):
        save_plot = path + str(i) + '.png'
        plt.ylabel("Population")
        plt.title(str(i))
        plt.legend(loc=4)
        plt.savefig(save_plot)
        plt.close()
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. :) Thank you men.. 
Is it possible to put 5 towns in each plot? Because, now I get 185 plots, and I want to less than that. :D

Comment: @Neven I updated my code to plot 5 cities at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply transpose your lists with `zip`
in order to convert `x, y` pairs to lists:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dictionary_town = {'Berlin': [[1, 333]],
 'London': [[1, 111], [2, 555]],
 'Paris': [[1, 444], [2, 222], [3, 999]]}


for i, town in enumerate(dictionary_town):
    x, y = zip(*dictionary_town[town])
    save_plot = 'path'+str(i)+'.png'

    plt.style.use('dark_background')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 20))
    plt.scatter(x, y, s=30,label=town, alpha=0.5)
    plt.ylabel("Population", fontsize=50)
    plt.title(str(i), fontsize=50)
    plt.legend(fontsize=30, markerscale=0.5, ncol=1)
    plt.savefig(save_plot)
    plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: I get a key error. :/ 
KeyError: 'None of [[[1.0, 0.07841227279285981], [2.0, 0.08206794681681895], [3.0, 0.08595926719786834], [4.0, 0.06782354709176948], [9995.0, 0.011077215571876565], [9996.0, 0.003400169925570253]]] are in the [index]'

Comment: Do you store your dataset in a pandas dataframe?